# How can we bulk update records using CRecordset

Tags: c++, database, mfc, odbc

I have an mfc application that uses CRecordsets to fetch and update/insert data.

I was able to implement bulk row fetching, but I'm now looking to implement bulk row updating/inserting/deleting using a derived CRecordset.

Has anyone done that? Can you provide code examples?

Comment: What data types do you fetch in bulk?

Comment: I need to be able to fetch almost every type : bool byte short long float double binary text guid...

Comment: So text fetching in bulk worked for you? I'm asking because I have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155374/implementing-bulk-record-fetching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled on an old post describing how to implement bulk row updating on a CRecordset.
First, you have to implement [bulk row fetching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77dcbckz.aspx) on your recordset(You can also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155374/implementing-bulk-record-fetching) for an example)

Once you recordset works for fetching data, it's quite simple.

```
//Declare your recordset
CMyRecordsetBulk regSetBulk(&myDatabase);

//Open it
regSetBulk.Open(NULL, NULL, CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch);

//Select the row you want to change
regSetBulk.SetRowsetCursorPosition(nRow);

//Update the value(s) you need to change.
regSetBulk.m_pnPrecision = 21;

//Set the length of the data in the field you modified (the "Precision" field is a byte)
regSetBulk.m_plnPrecision = 1;


//Do the same thing for a couple of other rows

regSetBulk.SetRowsetCursorPosition(++nRow);
regSetBulk.m_pnPrecision = 32;
regSetBulk.m_plnPrecision = 1;

regSetBulk.SetRowsetCursorPosition(++nRow);
regSetBulk.m_pnPrecision = 21;
regSetBulk.m_plnPrecision = 1;

regSetBulk.SetRowsetCursorPosition(++nRow);
regSetBulk.m_pnPrecision = 12;
regSetBulk.m_plnPrecision = 1;

//Update the rows and check for errors
int nRetCode;
AFX_ODBC_CALL(::SQLSetPos(regSetBulk.m_hstmt, NULL, SQL_UPDATE, SQL_LOCK_NO_CHANGE)); 
regSetBulk.CheckRowsetError(nRetCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `CDatabase::ExecuteSQL`. Doing updates by looping through as CRecordset can't be something you really want to do. A CRecordSet is only useful if you work with single entries, but not whole sets of data.

Comment: In fact, using a CRecordset to insert data is generally faster than using CDatabase::ExecuteSQL. I recently experienced a case with msAccess where using CRecordset instead of ExecuteSQL reduced the insert time from 40 to 3 seconds.

Comment: Debug/step into the recordset class and see what it does: creating a sql-statement and executing it!

Comment: It's more complex than that. CRecordset Class do variable and parameter binding and other stuff that can speed up the treatment.

Comment: But who says you can execute only one INSERT at a time?! Create a lot of them and execute only once, you'll save a lot of db-roundtrips!

Comment: And how would you do that? CDatabase::ExecuteSQL executes only one statement at a time

Comment: Are you aware of an MFC database object that can execute multiple statements?

Comment: strSQL = "insert bla bla; insert bla bla;"

Comment: CDatabase::ExecuteSQL doesnt support that.

Comment: Sure it does. I do that all the time. I am using SQL Server, maybe other ODBC clients can't do that.

Comment: You're right,before posting the may 11th comment,  I tested it with oracle and access and it did not work, but sql server works. My app must support those 3 bd... thks for the help