# Implementing bulk record fetching

Tags: c++, database, mfc, fetch, bulk

At the start of my program, I need to read data from a MS Access database (.mdb) into a drop down control. This is done so that whenever the user types in that control, the application can auto-complete.

Anyway, the reading from database took forever so I thought I'd implement bulk row fetching.

This is the code I have:

```
CString sDsn;
CString sField;
sDsn.Format("ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s",sDriver,sFile);
TRY
{
    // Open the database
    database.Open(NULL,false,false,sDsn);

    // Allocate the rowset
    CMultiRowset recset( &database );

    // Build the SQL statement
    SqlString =  "SELECT NAME "
            "FROM INFOTABLE";

    // Set the rowset size. These many rows will be fetched in one bulk operation
    recset.SetRowsetSize(25);

    // Open the rowset
    recset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, SqlString, CRecordset::readOnly | CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch);

    // Loop through each rowset
    while( !recset.IsEOF() )
    {
        int rowsFetched = (int)recset.GetRowsFetched(); // This value is always 1 somehow
        for( int rowCount = 1; rowCount <= rowsFetched; rowCount++ )
        {
            recset.SetRowsetCursorPosition(rowCount);
            recset.GetFieldValue("NAME",sField);
            m_nameDropDown.AddString(sField);
        }

        // Go to next rowset
        recset.MoveNext();
    }

    // Close the database
    database.Close();
}
CATCH(CDBException, e)
{
    // If a database exception occured, show error msg
    AfxMessageBox("Database error: "+e->m_strError);
}
END_CATCH;
```

`MultiRowset.cpp` looks like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "afxdb.h"
#include "MultiRowset.h"

// Constructor
CMultiRowset::CMultiRowset(CDatabase *pDB)
   : CRecordset(pDB)
{
    m_NameData = NULL;
    m_NameDataLengths = NULL;

    m_nFields = 1;
    CRecordset::CRecordset(pDB);
}

void CMultiRowset::DoBulkFieldExchange(CFieldExchange *pFX)
{
   pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::outputColumn);
   RFX_Text_Bulk(pFX, _T("[NAME]"), &m_NameData, &m_NameDataLengths, 30);
}
```

`MultiRowset.h` looks like:

```
#if !defined(__MULTIROWSET_H_AD12FD1F_0566_4cb2_AE11_057227A594B8__)
#define __MULTIROWSET_H_AD12FD1F_0566_4cb2_AE11_057227A594B8__

class CMultiRowset : public CRecordset
{
public:
      // Field data members
      LPSTR m_NameData;

      // Pointers for the lengths of the field data
      long* m_NameDataLengths;

      // Constructor
      CMultiRowset(CDatabase *);

      // Methods
      void DoBulkFieldExchange(CFieldExchange *);
};

#endif
```

And in my database, the `INFOTABLE` looks like:

```
NAME    AGE
----    ---
Name1   Age1
Name2   Age2
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

All I need to do is only *read* the data from the database. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? My code right now behaves exactly like a normal fetch. There's no bulk fetching happening.

**EDIT:**

I just poked around in `DBRFX.cpp` and found out that `RFX_Text_Bulk()` initializes my passed `m_NameData` as `new char[nRowsetSize * nMaxLength]`!

This means `m_NameData` is only a character array! I need to fetch multiple names, so wouldn't I need a 2D character array? The strangest thing is, the same `RFX_Text_Bulk()` initializes my passed `m_NDCDataLengths` as `new long[nRowsetSize]`. Why in the world would a character array need an array of lengths?!

Comment: what's the size of "[NAME]" field in your database?

Comment: @Goldorak84, 15 characters max.

Comment: In fact, m_NameData represents an array of character arrays. m_NDCDataLengths represents the lenghts of each strings in m_NameData

Comment: @Goldorak84, But `m_nameData` is initialized as `new char[nRowsetSize * nMaxLength];`. Doesn't that make it a character array of length `nRowsetSize * nMaxLength`?

Comment: There's something wrong with the CMultiRowset constructor. You should remove CRecordset::CRecordset(pDB); at the end of the function. It may reset m_nFields to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. To fetch the values, 
I would change your

```
        for( int rowCount = 1; rowCount <= rowsFetched; rowCount++ )
        {
            recset.SetRowsetCursorPosition(rowCount);
            recset.GetFieldValue("NAME",sField);
            m_nameDropDown.AddString(sField);
        }
```

by something like this

```
for( int nPosInRowset = 0; nPosInRowset < rowsFetched; nPosInRowset++ )
{
    //Check if value is null
    if (*(recset.m_NameDataLengths + nPosInRowset) == SQL_NULL_DATA)
        continue;    

    CString csComboString;
    csComboString = (recset.m_NameData + (nPosInRowset * 30)); //Where 30 is the size specified in RFX_Text_Bulk

    m_nameDropDown.AddString(csComboString);
}
```

EDIT: To fetch more than one row, remove the CRecordset::forwardOnly option

EDIT 2 : You can also keep CRecordset::forwardonly, but add the CRecordset::useExtendedFetch option

Comment: I did try this. Problem is, `rowsFetched` is always 1!

Comment: On what kind of database are you connecting to?

Comment: It's an MS Access database (.mdb)

Comment: I edited my post : To fetch more than one row, remove the CRecordset::forwardOnly option

Comment: You can also keep CRecordset::forwardonly, but add the CRecordset::useExtendedFetch option

Comment: Okay so now, `rowsFetched` = 25. [From the MSDN documentation for `CRecordset::Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkkwdf0(v=vs.80).aspx), _"If you specify the option CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch on a forward-only recordset, then CRecordset::useExtendedFetch will be turned on automatically."_. That's why I didn't use it. Oh well.

Comment: There's a fundamental problem with the way these text strings are treated. `m_nameData` is of type `LPSTR` (AKA `char *`). `RFX_Text_Bulk` is called by passing `&m_nameData` into the `prgStrVals` argument. `RFX_Text_Bulk` then allocates memory for `*prgStrVals` as `new char[nRowsetSize * nMaxLength]`. By my understanding, __this means `m_nameData` is a character array!__ Shouldn't `m_nameData` be of type `LPSTR *` (AKA `char **`)?

Comment: It would have been more logical to use LPSTR *, but if we look for performance, it's faster to allocate only one new char[nRowsetSize * nMaxLength] instead of (nRowsetSize) times new char[nMaxLength]. If you use the code provided above, you should be able to fill your combo box. Does this answer your problem?

Comment: Okay I just modified your `CString` assignment to `csComboString.Format("%s", (recset.m_NameData + (nPosInRowset * 30)));` and bingo! This works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, what rowset size would you suggest?

Comment: I use a rowset of 50. I made tests with 100 and 1000, and didn't notice a difference. Glad I could help!

Comment: After all this, I notice that there is no noticeable difference in my application .__.

Comment: A way to solve this is to, when your form first loads, fill your combobox only with the selected value. Then, implement the ON_CBN_SETFOCUS event to fill completely your combobox. Your combo will fill only when the user focuses (before click) on it. It works very well in my application

Answer (score 3):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77dcbckz.aspx#_core_how_crecordset_supports_bulk_row_fetching you have to open CRecordset with CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch flag before call SetRowsetSize:

> To implement bulk row fetching, you must specify the
>   CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch option in the dwOptions parameter of the
>   Open member function. To change the setting for the rowset size, call
>   SetRowsetSize.

Comment: That link seems to be broken. Also from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77dcbckz(v=vs.80).aspx), `After you have initialized the rowset size, call the Open member function. Here you must specify the CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch option`. This seems contradictory.

Comment: I have fixed the link. Yes, you are correct. Try to check that bulk fetching is implemented - call GetRowsetSize before SetRowsetSize: {quote} Before opening your recordset object, you can define a rowset size with the SetRowsetSize member function. The rowset size specifies how many records should be retrieved during a single fetch. When bulk row fetching is implemented, the default rowset size is 25. If bulk row fetching is not implemented, the rowset size remains fixed at 1.{quote}

Comment: The rowset size seems to be set correctly. I'm setting it to 25 currently. `GetRowsetSize()` returns 25 too.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same problem. 
You should use in `recset.Open()` call for `dwOptions` parameter only `CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch`, and not `CRecordset::readOnly | CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch`.
Hope this helps someone...

**EDIT:-** After re-check here is the situation - when using bulk recordset and opening with `CRecordset::forwardOnly` and `CRecordset::readOnly`, you must also specify `CRecordset::useExtendedFetch` in `dwOptions`. For other types of scrolling, using `CRecordset::readOnly | CRecordset::useMultiRowFetch` is just fine.